# Ubuntu - Wake On Lan stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, wake-on-lan

On a dual boot computer (Ubuntu Desktop 19.04 first / Windows 10 Pro second) I set up WakeOnLan on the ubuntu side with the command :

`sudo ethtool -s eno1 wol g`

I also installed gnome-tweak-tool in order to stop the computer from entering sleep mode when closing the lid.

After that i tried to wake up the computer from another host (a WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 on a win10 host) with the `wakeonlan` tool using the command :

`wakeonlan -i 192.168.1.255 c8:d3:ff:XX:81:XX`

It was working on every configurations possible :

- Lid open, sleeping
- Lid open, turned off
- Lid closed, sleeping
- Lid closed, turned off

But after a few try and retry on those 4 configurations possible, it started to not working anymore.
And now it only work when :

- Lid open, sleeping
- Lid closed, sleeping

In other word it doesn't wake the computer anymore when it is totally turned off (it was working at the beginning) and I've changed nothing.

I don't know where this behavior can come from.

Edit : While I'm writing this post I'm trying again, and everything works fine again. I'll ask the question anyway just to know if that's a common/known behavior.

Comment: And this morning it doesn't work. How could I troubleshooting this...